# H2O Flow: Run all cells programmatically

Tags: h2o

I import a flow-File using following curl command

```
curl http://localhost:54321/3/NodePersistentStorage.bin/notebook/my-model \
     -H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
     -H "Cookie: _gcl_au=123456" \
     -F "file=@path/to/my-model.flow"
```

The flow file get's imported.

**Question:** Do you know if there is a REST/HTTP-call to run all commands which are contained in the flow file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

People don't really automate Flows since there are scripting APIs for R and python.
But, there are some ancient tricks you can try to revive if you really want to.  You won't find any support for them, though.

Take a look at this ancient commit from 2015 which has the run-flow.coffee and run-flow.js scripts:

https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-3/tree/cd026d6dd71085c6f1fa91d5a27216b9ab86b39a/scripts

Note it requires a client-side phantomjs to work, which might defeat the point for you.

Sometime in the past these files were actually deleted from the top-of-tree repo, but you can still fish them out from history and try to revive the concept if you think it's useful for you.

Comment: Thank you, I will use one of the APIs. A workaround with phantomjs sounds hacky.